# typescript: Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '("a" | "b" | "c")[]'

Tags: typescript

```
function pick<T, K extends keyof T> (obj: T, keys: K[]): Pick<T, K> {
  return keys.reduce((result, key) => {
    result[key] = obj[key]
    return result
  }, {} as any)
}

const keys = ['b', 'c']
const o = {a: 1, b: '2', c: 3}
const picked = pick(o, ['b', 'c']) // ok
const picked2 = pick(o, keys) // error
```

Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '("a" | "b" | "c")[]'.

I just want to dynamic pick keys, how to do

Answer (score 0):

`keys` is created as `string[]`, but when you use `Pick` it creates string-literal types. You can solve this by using a type for `o` and using `keyof` that type. A way to write this with minimal changes would be:

```
const o = {a: 1, b: '2', c: 3}
const keys: (keyof typeof o)[] = ['b', 'c']
```

You will still get an error if you try to do `const keys: (keyof typeof o)[] = ['b', 'd']`, so you still get the type safety you're after.

I would recommend creating a type for `o` and using that, e.g.

```
interface O {
  a: number;
  b: string;
  c: number;
}
const keys: (keyof O)[] = ['b', 'c']
```